# HAproxy not working for multiple sites

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to use single HAproxy Loadbalancer for multiple sites, but only one site is working for me `cp_nodes`, when I try to access second website it redirects to first website only.

```
global
   log /dev/log local0
   log /dev/log local1 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log global
   mode http
   option httplog
   option dontlognull
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000

#Application Setup
frontend http_front
  bind *:80
  #redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  stats uri /haproxy?stats
  acl cp_domains hdr(host) -i cloud.one.net
  acl admin_doamins hdr(host) -i cloud.two.net
  use_backend cp_nodes if cp_domains
  use_backend admin_nodes if admin_doamins # Not working, redirects to cp_nodes onlye 


frontend https_front
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/cloud.pem
  stats uri /haproxy?stats
  acl cp_domains hdr(host) -i cloud.one.net
  acl admin_doamins hdr(host) -i cloud.two.net
  use_backend cp_nodes if cp_domains
  use_backend admin_nodes if admin_doamins

backend cp_nodes
  balance roundrobin
  server siteone.net 18.24.162.155:443 ssl check verify none
  server sitetwo.net 18.24.162.142:443 ssl check verify none

backend admin_nodes
  balance roundrobin
  server siteone.net:8081 18.24.162.155:8081
  server sitetwo.net:8081 18.24.162.142:8081
```

**Log File**

```
Dec 27 07:37:07 lb1 haproxy[21927]: Proxy http_front started.
Dec 27 07:37:07 lb1 haproxy[21927]: Proxy https_front started.
Dec 27 07:37:07 lb1 haproxy[21927]: Proxy cp_nodes started.
Dec 27 07:37:07 lb1 haproxy[21927]: Proxy admin_nodes started.
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Please show what HAProxy is logging for the requests that are getting "redirected."

Comment: @gf_ HA-Proxy version 1.6.3 2015/12/25

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this what I can see in logger

[root@lb1 ~]# tail -f /var/log/haproxy.log

Dec 27 07:35:03 lb1 haproxy[21889]: Proxy http_front started.
Dec 27 07:35:03 lb1 haproxy[21889]: Proxy https_front started.
Dec 27 07:35:03 lb1 haproxy[21889]: Proxy cp_nodes started.
Dec 27 07:35:03 lb1 haproxy[21889]: Proxy admin_nodes started.

Comment: These log entries suggest your actual requests are not hitting HAProxy at all.  From the proxy, simulate a request with `curl -v 'http://127.0.0.1' -H 'Host: cloud.two.net'`, note whether this is logged (it should be) then troubleshoot accordingly.

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue, but before putting this into production, you should update your version.  HAProxy 1.6.11 is the current 1.6 release and numerous bugs have been fixed since 1.6.3.